# export class vs functions

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

In case of utility module, I can have either class with static methods or just export methods. I think the first solution is better, though I saw a lot of implementations with second option. Are there any "nuances" here which I am not considering?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that a **class** with static methods is better for the following reasons:

- If your class name is `Utils`, all imports will by default import it as `Utils` too. With exported functions however, they *could* be imported as `Utils` yet that would only be a convention , one that likely won't be the case in all the different places.
- A class named `Utils` in a file named `utils.js` with all the utility methods neatly grouped together is aesthetically more pleasant than flat functions defined all over the place.
- A class could have `properties` that are used among its methods, for this you'd need [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) though. Again, much nicer than variables defined all over the place.

Comment: Is the babel module really needed for simple variables within classes? Can't you just do `this.variableName = "hey"` in the constructor

Comment: @JoshYolles It's definitely not necessary but it does make it look more pleasing to the eyes to have `static variableName` defined on top before even the `constructor()`. It could similarly be argued the class itself and its constructor aren't necessary neither and we could get it perfectly done with a factory function instead; It's just a fine line between what makes more sense to us humans.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting methods is safer because you don't give access to class properties. Note also that in javascrpt the concept of class does not have a lot of sense, it's been introduced to make feel more confortable developers with oo languages background. Try to work with Object prototyping instead.

Comment: I mentioned, in case of utility module, i.e, it contains only functions and there is no any property.

Comment: Your answer sounds self-contradictory, _if_ they were introduced as mere syntactic sugar, _then_ they should be considered better already, as the question is mostly about style.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options I can think of, if the methods are intended to be a utility method on another class, you could use handbaked mixins: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/classes_and_objects/mixins or rely on something similar in underscore/lowdash

If you want the encapsulation of methods and still have the ability to extend, you can do this:

```
class Foo
  foo = -> alert 'foo'

  @static: -> foo()


Foo.static() #=> 'foo'

Foo.foo #=> undefined
new Foo().foo #=> undefined

class Bar extends Foo

Bar.static() # => 'foo'
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ne7ccxk/

Comment: These samples look so ugly to the eyes.